# Phonegap / Web SQL: Why does an IF after the tx.transaction fire before the tx.transaction

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

My Phonegap app checks for a code in database on the device (WebSQL). If it finds the database and a record, it opens the page, otherwise it calls a function addActivationCode() which displays a form to ask for a code to be entered.

The part that is bugging me is that when the Database exists and the record is there, why does the IF at the bottom get called before the tx.executeSQL?

I have tested this in Chrome using alerts and the IF is definitely called before the onDeviceReady function completes.

When the database is found, var len is set to a count.  However, the IF is tested first so len==0 and the form is displayed, then the tx.executeSql runs and displays the page over the form.

Is it possible to prevent this behaviour somehow?

(This is the web browser version of the code.  I'm using JQuery):

```
$(document).on('pageinit','#home',function(){

  $("#activation_form").hide();

  checkDB(); 

  function checkDB() {

    db = window.openDatabase('TEST','1.0','test',2*1024);

    var len = 0;
    var act_code = "";

    db.transaction( function (tx){

        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM TEST',[],function(tx,results){

            var i;

            len = results.rows.length;

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
              act_code = results.rows.item(i).actcode;
            }

           build_page(act_code);

        }, null);


    if (len === 0){ 
        addActivationCode();
    }
  });
  }
});
```

Why does this IF get called before the tx.executeSQL is run? var len does not get set, even though the database exists.  After a few seconds the tx.executeSql runs and var len gets set to a value and build_page is called.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The **db.transaction()** call is a Asynchronous call that means the function call will return immediately with the function that is passed as an argument running in Async mode. 
It will **not wait** for the function that is passed as parameter to finish execution.
As a result your **IF** statement is executed **before** the **tx.()** call **finishes** execution.
The same explanation goes for the **tx.()** call. The **tx** call is a Async function.
You need to add the **IF** statement inside the `function(tx,results){...}`

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM TEST',[],function(tx,results){
        var i;

        len = results.rows.length;

        if (len === 0){ 
             addActivationCode();
        } else {

           for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
               act_code = results.rows.item(i).actcode;
           }

           build_page(act_code);
        }

    }, null);
```

Comment: Thank you. However, as far as I can see (which isn't that far in this case) if I put the IF inside the tx.executeSql, it will never be called if the database does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I re-organised the code and this works perfectly in Chrome:

```
function onDeviceReady() {

    db = window.openDatabase('TEST','1.0','TEST',2*1024);

    var len = 0;
    var act_code = "";

    db.transaction(findCode, onError1, addCode);

    function findCode(tx){

        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM TEST',[],loadPage,onError2);

    }

    function loadPage(tx,results){

        len = results.rows.length;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
          act_code = results.rows.item(i).actcode;
        }

        build_page(act_code);

    }

    function addCode(){

        if(len==0){                
            addActivationCode();                   
        }

    }

}
```